# how to display data in listview using android

Tags: android, listview

I am retrieving data from database and displaying records in simple textview but i want to display data in listview because i am performing some operation on click listview. I do not know how to do it, please help me how to display data in listview and edit my code. thanks.

code of retrieve data

```
public class RDatawithID extends Activity{ 
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;

ListView listCollege1;
ProgressBar proCollageList;
String Resp;

private ProgressDialog loading;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rdatawith_id);

    listCollege1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tasklist);
textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);


    System.out.println("In Oncreate method");

    getData();
}



private void getData() {
        String id = String.valueOf(1);
    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL+id;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RDatawithID.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    System.out.println("Response     - ----   "+response);
    String name="";
    String address="";
    String vc = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        Task1_ = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int x=0;x<result.length();x++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
            name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);

            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult.getText() + "\n" + "Name:\t" + name + "\nAddress:\t" + address + "\nVice Chancellor:\t" + vc);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: where is your adapter?

Comment: no i did not use adapter , without adapter i cant display data in listview

Comment: you have listview so you need to add your arraylist in adapter and need to st adapter also

Comment: please can you update my code .

Comment: Go through this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create CollegeDataModel.java

```
public class CollegeDataModel {
String cName;
String cAddress;
String cVC;

public CollegeDataModel(String name, String Address, String vc){

setName(name);
setAddress(address);
setVC(vc);
}

public String getName() {
    return cName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.cName = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return cAddress;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.cAddress = address;
}

public String getVc() {
    return cVC;
}

public void setVC(String vc) {
    this.cVc = vc;
   }

 }
```

2- Create layout.item_college_data_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Address" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="VC" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

3- Create adapter ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<CollegeDataModel> collegeDataList;


public ListAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<CollegeDataModel> listItems ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.collegeDataList = listItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return collegeDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_college_data_list, null);

        TextView txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView txtAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        TextView txtVC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvVC);

        viewHolder.tvName = txtName;
        viewHolder.tvAddress  = txtAddress;
        viewHolder.tvVC  = txtVC;
        v.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) v.getTag();
    }



    viewHolder.tvName.setText(collegeDataList.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.tvAddress.setText(collegeDataList.get(position).getAddress());
    viewHolder.tvVC.setText(collegeDataList.get(position).getVC());

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvAddress;
    TextView tvVC;
  }

 }
```

4- update your RDatawithID.java activity code

```
public class RDatawithID extends Activity{ 
   private Button buttonGet;
   private TextView textViewResult;

   ListView listCollege1;
   ProgressBar proCollageList;
   String Resp;

   ArrayList <CollegeDataModel> collegeDataList;
   ListAdapter listAdapter;

   private ProgressDialog loading;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_rdatawith_id);

     listCollege1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tasklist);
     textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

     collegeDataList = new ArrayList<>();

     System.out.println("In Oncreate method");

    getData();
  }



  private void getData() {
    String id = String.valueOf(1);
    if (id.equals("")) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return;
      }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please 
     wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL+id;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new 
    Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        loading.dismiss();
        showJSON(response);
        }
      },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Toast.makeText(RDatawithID.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  }

  private void showJSON(String response){
     System.out.println("Response     - ----   "+response);
     String name="";
     String address="";
     String vc = "";
     try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
       JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
       Task1_ = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(int x=0;x<result.length();x++) {
          JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
          name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
          address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
          vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);

        collegeDataList.add(x, new CollegeDataModel(name, address, vc));
        //textViewResult.setText(textViewResult.getText() + "\n" + "Name:\t" + name + "\nAddress:\t" + address + "\nVice Chancellor:\t" + vc);
    }

    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(RDatawithID.this, collegeDataList);
    listCollege1.setAdapter(listAdapter );
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice 
Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I update my code, data is fetching in response but data is not displaying in listview. Please can you explain where is problem.

Comment: Thank u so much..You saved my time..I solved my problem.just added listCollege1.setAdapter(listAdapter); this line in RDatawithID.java.Thanks..great answer